# Not able to view the created nodes in Browser

Tags: java, neo4j, neo4jclient

I just started with `neo4j` few days back. I executed the sample *hello world* example given in the tutorial, showing *the relationship between two persons*.
But,I am **not able to view the nodes in the browser**. I do not know where I am making mistake. I have given the `db` *path* as the *location* where it is stored in my drive. Please help me with this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you perhaps share a screenshot?

Did you a execute a query from the left side pane? Like "Get some data"

Note that there is a switch between tabular and visualization view on the bottom right of each visualization view.

See my blog post: http://jexp.de/blog/2014/06/styling-neo4j-server-visualisation/

Comment: I included neo4j in eclipse and created nodes.